# Laravel Form run JS function onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a function that I want called on submission of my Laravel Form for Ajax purposes.  How can I go about this where the page does not submit and reload?

This works: (but the Enter btn does not execute)

```php
<?php echo Form::open(); ?>
    <?php echo Form::button('Search', array('id'=>'searchbtn', 'class'=>'button radius right', 'onclick'=>'myFunction(this.form)')); ?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

This does not:

```php
<?php echo Form::open(array('onsubmit' => 'myFunction(this)')); ?>
    <?php echo Form::submit('Search', null, array('id'=>'searchbtn', 'class'=>'button radius right')); ?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Comment: Does your `myFunction` return false (or prevent event propagation in some other way)?

Comment: Very good observation.  There were a cpl other gotchas but I did get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
<?php echo Form::open(array(null, null, 'onsubmit' => 'myFunction(this); return false;')); ?>
    <?php echo Form::submit('Search', null, array('id'=>'searchbtn', 'class'=>'button radius right')); ?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Yayy.  Now I could use my Enter button!

Comment: how do you access the form data? when I log out the value of `this` I get the html of the form, not the values

Comment: You have to say .value, so try this.value or maybe this["fname"].value